# How to access google/github respository behind VPN?

Tags: git, proxy, firewall, vpn

I cannot check out both code.google.com and github projects via git, but I can normally access them from IE/Firefox browser. There were a lot of discussions about git proxy configuration behind firewall but unfortunately none of these discussions is suitable for my problem.

Here are the messages while I am trying to access code.google.com

```
Cloning into 'smart-adaptive-makefile'...
* Couldn't find host code.google.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to proxy proxyconf port 1080 (#0)
*   Trying 147.243.224.17...
* 0x80077208 is at send pipe head!
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x8007fba0; (connection #0)
* Connection timed out after 300015 milliseconds
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => COMPLETED handle 0x8007fba0; (connection #-5000)
* STATE: COMPLETED => MSGSENT handle 0x8007fba0; (connection #-5000)
* Closing connection #0
* Couldn't find host code.google.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to proxy proxyconf port 1080 (#0)
*   Trying 147.243.224.17...
* 0x80077208 is at send pipe head!
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x8007fad8; (connection #0)
* Connection timed out after 300032 milliseconds
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => COMPLETED handle 0x8007fad8; (connection #-5000)
* STATE: COMPLETED => MSGSENT handle 0x8007fad8; (connection #-5000)
* Closing connection #0
error: Connection timed out after 300032 milliseconds while accessing https://panruochen@code.google.com/p/smart-adaptive-makefile/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

BTW, my IE/Firefox uses an automatic configuration script instead of manually configuration proxy server. In this case, how should I configure git?

BR,ruochen

Comment: are you accessing git repository using https or git protocol?

Comment: I access git repository via https

Answer (score 2):

I manage to access any external repo behind firewall without any issue, provided I have my proxy settings in place:

```
HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy.server:port
HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy.server:port
```

Note that both addresses the same proxy address (in my case, an http, not https one), with the username and password for that proxy (not for GitHub)

`~/.netrc` (or `%HOME%/_netrc` on Windows, if you defined explicitly an `%HOME%` environment variable) is only used for the external repo authentication:

```
machine github.com
login user
password passwd
```

See "[Git - How to use `.netrc` file on windows to save user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password/6031266#6031266)" for more.

Comment: Basically your solution works. Simply setting http.proxy in git is okay. It is not necessary to setting HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY environment variables. I got the problem because I used to set http.proxy directly to the automatic configuration script which was copied from the browser setting. Now I open that script and manually pick up the proxy server address and set it to git and solve the problem.

Comment: @PRC true, but I need those for other programs to work, and I prefer don't leave my username / password in git config files. I define those variable in a DOS session each time I need them.